# Angular 2/4 Will ElementRef break angular universal?

Tags: angular, typescript, universal

I have a question:

Will using `ElementRef.nativeElement` to read a property value (e.g. 'scrollHeight') count as a DOM interaction and therefore break Angular Universal?

ElementRef seems to be the only way to read a property from an element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037240/5565132

Example:

HTML:

```
<div #test1></div>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('test1') test1: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.test1.nativeElement.scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: Yes. Passing `this.test1.nativeElement` to a `Renderer` would be fine, but accessing any property or method of `nativeElement` won't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So this means that reading a property from nativeElement is okay and won't break anything but setting it requires Renderer(2), correct?

Comment: No, the `Renderer(2)` doesn't provide anything to read from `nativeElement`

Comment: Okay. Are there any other ways to read a property from an element? e.g. test1 in this case? Because my app has some logic which depends on a element property value

Comment: No. AFAIK the only thing you can do is to check if the code actually runs on the browsers UI thread and only then read otherwise skip that code. I don't know how to check that but I have seen it mentioned.

Comment: Okay. Depending some logic on an element's property value doesn't seem like an exceptional thing to me or am I missing something? Why isn't this possible "the angular way"? Still thank you for your answers!

Comment: When run on the server or in WebWorker the element just won't exist. The calls that update the DOM will be queued and then executed when the element is actually rendered in the browser. For read actions this would be way too complicated.