# Is there a way I can dynamically set the formControlName on an <input> element in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-forms

I'm working on writing a component intended to simplify/homogenize the way our forms look and interact. The code looks something like this:

**Example Usage**

```
...
<my-form-input labelKey = "email" controlName="emailAddress" [form]="userForm">
    <input myInput class="form-control" type="email" formControlName="emailAddress" />
</my-form-input>
...
```

You can see that `"emailAddress"` is passed to `MyFormInputComponent` as the `controlName` *and is passed a second time to the* `FormControlName` directive on the `<input>` element. I'd like to only pass this once so that my end user doesn't have to do this.

Is there a good way I can go about this, or is this just a constraint I should accept (if yes, an explanation of why this constraint exists would be welcome)? Code is shown below.

I've tried two approaches:

1. Setting a `@HostBinding("attr.formControlName")` annotation in the `MyInput` component. I can manipulate an attribute called `formcontrolname` on the element this way, but it doesn't trigger the directive that Angular Forms needs to properly register the control with the group.
2. Ask the user to supply `formControlName` to the `<input>` element and read the value off of this for the rest of the component. This might work, but I'd have to access the DOM directly through an `ElementRef`, [which is not recommended](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#properties). The recommended route for interacting with DOM -- `Renderer` -- [doesn't seem to expose any ability to read attributes either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41281143/3014905).

**my-form-input.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-form-input',
    templateUrl: './my-form-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-form-input.component.scss']
})
export class MyFormInputComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
    @Input()
    labelKey: string;

    @Input()
    controlName: string;

    @Input()
    form: FormGroup;

    @ContentChild(MyInputDirective)
    input: MyInputDirective;

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {        
        this.initInput();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the input we project into the template
     */
    private initInput() {
        this.input.updatePlaceholder(this.labelKey);
        // I'd like to somehow edit the FormControlName directive applied to the input here
    }
}
```

**my-form-input.component.html**

```
<label>{{ labelKey | translate }}</label>
<ng-content></ng-content>
<my-input-error [control]="form.controls[controlName]" [name]="labelKey | translate" />
```

**my-input.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myInput]'
})
export class myInputDirective implements OnInit {
    private placeholderKey = ""; 

    @HostBinding("placeholder")
    private placeholder: string;

    updatePlaceholder(placeholderKey: string) {
        this.placeholderKey = placeholderKey;
        this.placeholder = this.translateService.instant(this.placeholderKey);
    }

    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    }
}
```

**my-form-error.component.ts**

```
// Not shown since not relevant.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure the exact explanation, but some reasoning alludes to where I might have strayed.

I assumed that my component owned the elements that it was projecting, but I actually think this isn't true. Your opportunity to set attributes/directives is in the template. This means you are better off including any elements that you want to own/control into the template rather then just projecting them.

In this case, that leads you to making separate components for specific form controls (like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc). This is what I've ended up doing. This is better from a design endpoint anyway -- one component to wrap all possible form-controls was never going to happen. Either project a form control that duplicates some properties, like I do in the question, or create specific components. Or both (just make your most common form controls into components, wrap the one-off problems in your projecting component).

Here are some blogs that helped me find my way:

1. https://medium.com/@vadimkorr/implementing-nested-custom-controls-in-angular-5-c115c68e6b88
2. https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83